# How to read Data Object with IAIK wrapper 1.6.2

Tags: pkcs#11, safenet

my issue is I was using following versions of IAIK with Tokens

- Provider : 1.5
- Wrapper :1.4
- JCE : 5.25
- Safenet PKCS11 drivers : 10.2

Now I wpould like to use latest version :

- Provider : 1.6.2
- Wrapper :1.7
- JCE : 5.62
- Safenet PKCS11 drivers : 10.8 R2

The big issue is I can no longer read data object even with

```
 session.findObjectsInit(null);
```

With old versions, using following template I can get Data Object:

```
 private static GenericTemplate getTokenObjectTemplate3(String label) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(label != null);

        GenericTemplate template = new GenericTemplate();

        LongAttribute objectClassAttribute = new LongAttribute(PKCS11Constants.CKA_CLASS);
        objectClassAttribute.setLongValue(new Long(PKCS11Constants.CKO_DATA));
        template.addAttribute(objectClassAttribute);

        CharArrayAttribute labelAttribute = new CharArrayAttribute(PKCS11Constants.CKA_LABEL);
        labelAttribute.setCharArrayValue("oostatus".toCharArray());
        template.addAttribute(labelAttribute);

        BooleanAttribute tokenAttribute = new BooleanAttribute(PKCS11Constants.CKA_TOKEN);
        tokenAttribute.setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
        template.addAttribute(tokenAttribute);

        BooleanAttribute privateAttribute = new BooleanAttribute(PKCS11Constants.CKA_PRIVATE);
        privateAttribute.setBooleanValue(Boolean.FALSE);
        template.addAttribute(privateAttribute);

        CharArrayAttribute applicationAttribute = new CharArrayAttribute(PKCS11Constants.CKA_APPLICATION);
        applicationAttribute.setCharArrayValue(TOKEN_APPLICATION.toCharArray());
        template.addAttribute(applicationAttribute);

        return template;
    }
```

Now I'm using the following but in vain :

```
private static Data getTokenObjectTemplate4() {
        Data dataObjectTemplate = new Data();
        dataObjectTemplate.getLabel().setCharArrayValue(TOKEN_STATUS_LABEL.toCharArray());
        return dataObjectTemplate;
    }
```

Any help or peace of runing code please ?

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: That's it no error message but I can no longer get them with previous code...